# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null` error in my AngularJS application when I am using ng-grid.  As far as I can determine this only seems to occur when the page / browser is being resized.

I don't think this is causing the application any harm, but nevertheless is an issue that I'd like resolved if possible.  I've looked at the ng-grid project site and it doesn't give any details of whether it's fixed or not.

Does anyone know why this is happening and whether a fix is available?

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the error?

Comment: The error is occurring in the ng-grid source on line 349 and not my application.  You can see this happen by pressing F12 to bring up the developer tools in Chrome and then resize the developer tools window.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.7.

Comment: Are you in any way using `$rootScope` in combination with ng-grid?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `$rootScope` on the `$stateChangeStart` event to set up routes for ui-router in my `app.Run()` method.  However, `$rootScope` isn't used on the ng-grid page, but I suspect it's being affected by the `$rootScope` on the ui-router states?

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you set a breakpoint after the following line: `var ngEventProvider = function (grid, $scope, domUtilityService, $timeout)` and inspect the `$id` of `$scope`?

Comment: `$id` of `$scope` is  389 and is different values when reloading the page.  Does this help?

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm using Angular 1.3.9.

Comment: Wanted to make sure it wasn't the $rootScope. Will try to find the reason for your error.

Comment: It's no problem. Have you tried a newer version?

Comment: I recall trying a newer version of ng-grid which was too unstable, considering it was in beta so I thought I'd use a more stable version for now. Weird thing is the error message only appears when (1) load a page with no-grid, (2) navigate to another page then (3) go back to original page then resize the browser. Very bizarre.

Comment: Decided to upgrade ng-grid to version 3 and I don't get the error any longer.